# One Instagram business account managed by multiple users without sharing credentials

Tags: instagram

I'm looking for a solution to manage one business Instagram account with multiple different users without sharing the credentials of the master account.

I created an Instagram business account, created a Facebook page, linked both together and added some "editor" roles on the Facebook page as suggested in Instagram's help page. Unfortunately "editor" roles cannot publish on my instagram page, they cannot access it.

Is there a way to achieve this? I would basically like to have multiple users (with their own credentials) manage a single instagram page (to post, like, follow,...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done through Instagram or Facebook features, so there isnt an integrated way to do it. It could be coded with an unofficial API in php though.